# Suppose $H<G$, let $N=\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$, show $N$ is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I read in some text the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Denote $N=\bigcap_\limits{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$, then $N$ is the **largest** normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

It's easy to show $N<G$, since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ any conjugate $xHx^{-1}~(x\in G)$ of $H$ is also a subgroup of $G$, and the intersection of subgroups is also a subgroup. $N\lhd G$ is also easily shown, if $n\in N$ then for any $g\in G$ there exists $h\in H$ such that $n=ghg^{-1}$, and for any $x\in G$ we have $xnx^{-1}=x(ghg^{-1})x^{-1}=(xg)h(xg)^{-1}$. Since for any $g$ such an $h$ always exists and $x\mapsto xg$ is surjective, clearly $xnx^{-1}\in N$. $N\subseteq H$ because $1H1^{-1}=H$ is one of the intersecting subgroups.

It's left to show $N$ is the **largest** normal subgroup contained in $H$, which I do not know how to achieve. I appreciate any help or hint, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is a larger normal subgroup of $H$, i.e. some subgroup $N'$ exists such that
$$N \subseteq N' \subseteq H.$$
We need to show that $N' = N$. We only need to show that $N' \subseteq N$.

Take any $g \in N'$ and $x \in G$. Then $x^{-1} g x \in N' \subseteq H$, thus $g \in xHx^{-1}$. This is true for any $x \in G$, hence
$$g \in \bigcap_{x \in G} xHx^{-1} = N,$$
completing the proof.

Comment: Very concise, thanks! (Though there seems to be a small typo in the last equation.)

Comment: @Lu_Yinfeng Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HINT: show that any normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$ is contained on N